# Is there a precise meaning to F'd in the B - Scott Pilgrim fight scene

Tags: scott-pilgrim-vs.-the-world

Roxy Richter is apparantly about to win the fight against Scott Pilgim and she says those words to her ex, Ramona Flowers

"Your BF's about to get F'd in the B"

[gif with quote](https://78.media.tumblr.com/687f2c9fd3283ea321e3f0e201043dfd/tumblr_oul3348dF91w8qokno1_500.gif)

[image]

BF is obviously boyfriend.     F'd in the B could mean a couple things, and it seems like it should be obvious, but it doesn't google or urban dictionary and I'm not sure what F'd in the B means.    F'd in the A has meaning and that urban dictionaries.   F'd in the B doesn't.

If F is a curse word, and I'm thinking it is, just type f**k or something like that but it could also mean foot.   And, yes, this feels like a dumb question with an obvious answer, but I honestly don't know what it means.

Comment: id have to say, She say, in the butt, Bob

Comment: But she's about to kick him.  Could be foot in the balls, I think it's a play on F'd in the A without literal meaning.  That's where I've come down, but I figured I'd ask and see if there's anything official.   The character Roxy says a few things that are plays on words, so it might not have literal meaning.

Comment: You never hear someone say ...in the balls

Comment: @JasonPSallinger  yeah, maybe I'm just overthinking it.   You're probably right.

Comment: It could be just Your BF is about to get Fries in a Bucket  (Im hungry right now)

Comment: It's a play on words meant to add humor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I always interpreted it as "f*cked in the butt". That makes sense in the context of the scene.

Comment: You're the 2nd person to say that.  That may be right.   Thanks.

Comment: It's funny to me that I've gotten so many points for such a vulgar answer! This community continues to surprise and delight me.

Comment: I got 0 votes up for the question.   I think the message is, you're 100% correct and it's an easy question.   I don't think it's up-votes for vulgarity or I'd have gotten one or two.   It was, on my part a 100% sincere question even if I was the only person on the planet who didn't figure it out.

Comment: @userLTK I clicked the "0" next to your question, and it showed me the breakdown of votes:  one up (yay!), and one down. The _average_ is zero. I had no doubt it was a sincere question; as you said, there are many options for each letter. It could be "f*ck", "foot", "butt", "balls", etc.

Comment: I would just like to point out that nobody uses "Butt" in Britain.  We say "F*cked in the bum" and I noticed the film has a British co-writer/producer/director.  The meaning remains the same however :D

Answer (score 5):

It does indeed mean "f***ed in the butt".

But the specific use of "F'd in the B" instead of, perhaps, the more common "F'd in the A" is because it reuses the letters "BF" from earlier in the sentence. This kind of fits the pattern of language used throughout the film.